# The equation $3a+5b=n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> For a given number $n$, how can we find out whether we have any non-negative values for $a$ and $b$ for the equation
>   $$3a+5b=n,$$
>   where $1\le n\le 100,000$.

For example: If $n=5$, then $a=0, b=1$.

Comment: Hi new user! $$\color{red}{\text{Welcome to Math.SE!}}$$ Don't worry about it now (since you're new) but you might like to know that we use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here (e.g. `$\theta$` for $\theta$).

Comment: I suggest studying [Bézout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a special case of the [Frobenius problem or coin problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem). You want to know for which $n$ it is possible to find nonnegative integers $a,b$ such that $3a+5b=n$. Take a look at the two-variable case on the Wikipedia page: It is always possible if $n>3\cdot5-3-5$, that is, $n>7$.

For values smaller then or equal to $7$, it is known that exactly half of them can be written in the form $3a+5b$. All you have to do is check them manually:

$0=3\cdot0+5\cdot0$,

$3=3\cdot1+5\cdot0$,

$5=3\cdot0+5\cdot1$,

and $6=3\cdot2+5\cdot0$.

The other half ($1$, $2$, $4$ and $7$) indeed can't be written in the desired form.

These are explicit solutions:

If $n=3k$, then we have $n=3\cdot k+5\cdot0$.

If $n=3k+1$ with $k>2$, then we can write $n=3\cdot(k-3)+5\cdot2$.

If $n=3k+2$ with $k>1$, then $n=3\cdot(k-1)+5\cdot1$.

This covers all integers $n>7$.

All other solutions can now be derived from these using [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Comment: Thank you very much for answer.How can we get a & b values?

Answer (score -1):

You should caclulate the coeficient of $x^n$ for the following generating function:
$$
G(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x^3)(1-x^5)}.
$$
If $[x^n]G(x) \neq 0$  then the equation $3a+5b=n$ has  solutions.

Comment: "You should..." Maybe "You could..." This seems quite a bad strategy.

Comment: @ Pedro Tamaroff. Thank you for correction.